# Liquibase migration fails with dropwizard

Tags: java, database, liquibase, dropwizard

If I put all my changesets in a single file, it works fine, but if I do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd">

  <includeAll path="migrations" />
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Then I get the error below. The migrations directory is in src/main/resources - any ideas where I'm going wrong? Thanks.

```
Exception in thread "main" liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: liquibase.exception.SetupException: /var/folders/m_/jvmrmqx90n54v276_xvtgxcw0000gn/T/liquibase-unzip5492890813073634394.dir/license/LICENSE.dom-documentation.txt (Not a directory)
    at liquibase.parser.core.xml.AbstractChangeLogParser.parse(AbstractChangeLogParser.java:27)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.getDatabaseChangeLog(Liquibase.java:225)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:200)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:190)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:186)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:179)
    at io.dropwizard.migrations.DbMigrateCommand.run(DbMigrateCommand.java:68)
    at io.dropwizard.migrations.DbCommand.run(DbCommand.java:52)
    at io.dropwizard.migrations.AbstractLiquibaseCommand.run(AbstractLiquibaseCommand.java:61)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:77)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:70)
    at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:80)
    at uk.co.wansdykehouse.pr.PRApplication.main(PRApplication.java:58)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.SetupException: /var/folders/m_/jvmrmqx90n54v276_xvtgxcw0000gn/T/liquibase-unzip5492890813073634394.dir/license/LICENSE.dom-documentation.txt (Not a directory)
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.includeAll(DatabaseChangeLog.java:367)
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.handleChildNode(DatabaseChangeLog.java:274)
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.load(DatabaseChangeLog.java:221)
    at liquibase.parser.core.xml.AbstractChangeLogParser.parse(AbstractChangeLogParser.java:25)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/folders/m_/jvmrmqx90n54v276_xvtgxcw0000gn/T/liquibase-unzip5492890813073634394.dir/license/LICENSE.dom-documentation.txt (Not a directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at liquibase.util.FileUtil.unzip(FileUtil.java:76)
    at liquibase.resource.ClassLoaderResourceAccessor.list(ClassLoaderResourceAccessor.java:87)
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.includeAll(DatabaseChangeLog.java:344)
    ... 15 more
```

Edit:

Curiously, this works:

```
<include file="migrations/00001_initial.xml" />
```

Comment: Maybe you should add your directory structure as well. `includeAll` just tries to identify the path, list all files in it and then it uses the `include` method on all the files. Also, you can try to add the `relativeToChangelogFile` option.

Comment: You could debug into the ClassLoaderResourceAccessor to see what it is trying to do. Is there anything else on your classpath in resources/migrations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be late to answer this question..but i know what is wrong here.You have missed '/' after 'migrations'. Look here for reference [Include all files](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/includeall.html)